# Textbox in data repeater made invisible does not mantain its view during scroll

Tags: c#, data-binding, datarepeater

I have created a form using `DataRepeater` and I have an XML file that I deserialize into a class.  I then created a `dataset` to represent the class. I bind the `dataset` to my `DataRepeater`.  I have also created some labels and textboxes and bind them to the appropriate data from my dataset.

The following are the codes:

```
 TagLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Tag");
 PrecedenceLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Precedence"); 
 DataTypeLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "DataType");           
 LengthLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Length");           
 ValueTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Value");           
 MaxTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Maximum");           
 MinTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Minimum");           
 OverflowTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds,"OverflowBehaviour");

 bindingsource.DataSource = ds;
 dataRepeater.DataSource = bindingsource;
 dataRepeater.DataMember = "Preference";
```

After this, I want to hide `ValueTextbox` if it's `DataTypeLebel` is `"Autoinrement"`. The following are the codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataRepeater.ItemCount; i++)            
{          
dataRepeater.CurrentItemIndex = i;

 if (((Label)dataRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls["DataTypeLabel"]).Text == "AutoIncrement")                
 {                    
 ((TextBox)dataRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls["ValueTextBox"]).Visible = false;           
 }    
 }
```

After I have done this and run the project, in this case according to my XML file, I am expecting only data repeater row 5 has its `ValueTextBox` hidden.  However, as I scroll the form. I can see some other rows showing invisible `VallueTextBox`.  It is worse when I scroll up and down and the hidden textboxes are every where.  Can anyone suggest what I have done wrong please?

I have also tried virtual mode and update the controls and make textbox invisible based on condition in the event handler `dataeRepeater_itemValueNeeded` and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a property in a conditional statement such as If…Then, you must also use an Else clause to specify the appearance when the condition is not met.
Try this:

```
if (((Label)dataRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls["DataTypeLabel"]).Text    == "AutoIncrement")                  
{                      

 ((TextBox)dataRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls["ValueTextBox"]).Visible = false;             

}      

else
{
 ((TextBox)dataRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls["ValueTextBox"]).Visible = true;         
}
```